# OS detection if useragent value is altered

Tags: php, user-agent

Using Php is it possible  to detect exact OS even if the browser agent value is altered?

Here is the case

If someone override Firefox useragent value using "general.useragent.override"

```
Actual: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0

Override: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.55.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10
```

$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] value will be totally fake. it's not useful even to detect correct Operating System.

Is there any Php solution in this situation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The only information you have is that supplied by the `User-agent` header, and if a user wants to send false information there is nothing you can do to detect it.

Comment: Thanks lonesomeday. 
I could see even Google fails when I altered useragent to iPad.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use JavaScript to find the screen size but not the os this is how to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(screen.width+'x'+screen.height);
</script>
```

but this can be changed by the client anyway as its on the client side on ios there is one way by setting up a mobile management profile temp to very the device but thats a lot of work for the client so only do that if you have to
But in most cases you cannot very its not mod